# Display big numbers in terminal

Tags: linux, terminal, zsh, tmux

`tmux` can display big time like the picture below, 
is there any way to display big numbers like that,
for example I want to show number of users in real time.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

To the extent of my knowledge, there is no such feature in tmux. You could use `watch` (part of the procps tools) and `figlet` to implement such a feature:

`watch` runs a command periodically and prints the output on the screen. It always clears the screen before running the command.

`figlet` renders a string in a ASCII-Art style font. There a several fonts availiable.

So for instance you could show the number of users on a system (at least on Linux) using the following command line:

`watch "who | wc -l | figlet -f big"`

Unfortunatly the text won't be centered, as it is with clock-mode.

Comment: Perhaps not all versions of figlet support this, but mine supports a `-c` which will center text within 80 columns (or whatever you want if you specify `-w`)